# Mongoose find query on subdocuments property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I need to perform a query on a MongoDB database using mongoose to select documents based on the value of properties contained in subdocuments.
These are my schemas:

```
type Map{
    id: ID
    date: String!
    parcels: [Parcel!]!
  }
type Parcel {
    id: Int
    name: String!
    x: Int!
    y: Int!    
  }
```

I'd like to find a parcel by coordinates at a given date, so I tried these queries but I always get null:

```
Map.find({date: "2022-06-15", parcels:{x: 10, y:20}})
Map.find({date: "2022-06-15", "parcels.x": 10, "parcels.y":20})
```

Is there any way to avoid retrieving all parcels and then selecting the one I'm looking for?